# bootstrap 4 modals fail to load data-remote when using .load in jquery's full version

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm unable to correctly load an internal / external page into any type of modal and or semi-transparent window. I have tried various load methods and for some reason I'm just missing the obvious and or there is a serious conflict I can't seem to find among the resources used. I'm using the attr data-remote.

I created a simple code pen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vgzemx

**The modal that loads the content:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5>Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-default close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The container with the modal buttons**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row p-5">
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_script" data-target="#myModal">Modal 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_testing" data-target="#myModal">Modal 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation" data-target="#myModal">Modal 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacity_management" data-target="#myModal">Modal 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery to load the content:**

```
<script>
$('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function() {
    $($(this).data("target") + ' .modal-content').load($(this).attr('data-remote'));
});
</script>
```

**Here is the full snippet, not working and showing a generic error:**

```js
$('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function() {
    $($(this).data("target") + ' .modal-content').load($(this).attr('data-remote'));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5>Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-default close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row p-5">
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_script" data-target="#myModal">Modal 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_testing" data-target="#myModal">Modal 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation" data-target="#myModal">Modal 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacity_management" data-target="#myModal">Modal 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Yet no matter what I try I can not load any external content page. I know the original feature has been deprecated in 4. I have seen others state they found a workaround. Yet nothing works with the current code as loaded, that I could find.

Is there a better way to handle this? I've been struggling and can't seem to come up with a solution on my own.

Thank you for all that look at this and hope this helps to contribute to others that are looking for a way to make this feature work.

Comment: What error are you getting? Your codepen is showing a CORS error...

Comment: You can't use `.load()` which is a shorthand for ajax request, on an URL you do not own.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette What can I use to achieve this then? Thank you.

Comment: @danboh it just does not work, no error that I see directly.

Comment: You just can't. Have a look at [Why can't we use Ajax outside our domain?](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I can't even use it on my own domain, so it's very strange, thanks for the cross domain ref:

Comment: What is `click.modal.data-api`? Try with just `click`.. That first argument is for events (you can have many, space separated). Use a resource from your own domain. Check for errors in console too. Lastly, I would load the result in `.modal-body` instead of `.modal-content`... ;)